# Why frictionless joints are assumed in pin-joint truss analysis?

Tags: equilibrium, statics, structural-beam

In pin-jointed truss analysis, we consider some assumptions.
One of them is that they have friction-less joints.

1. Why do we have this assumption?
2. What would happen if the joints were to have friction? How does it affect the analysis?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What is to be gained by incorporating friction?

Comment: I think friction should introduce a moment. Do we assume friction-less joints because we cannot determine the magnitude of the friction(and the resulting moment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No friction in the pin joints means none of the joints can transmit bending moments. This simplifies the analysis. Including friction in the pin joints means it becomes possible to transmit bending moments across the joints. In this case it is possible to get the structure to be statically indeterminate (more unknowns than the number of equations) if the pin joints can transmit bending moments.

Comment: Can you please tell me how joints transmit bending moments?

Comment: assume the truss supports a load in one segment which bends a horizontal beam downward between two pinned joints. this means the ends of the beam at the pinned joints will rotate upwards. If the pinned joints at the ends of this beam have no friction, then the beam ends can freely rotate. However, if friction is present in the pin joint, then the loaded beam's ends cannot rotate freely: they hence apply bending loads to the adjacent beams.